# Deny entering special character in textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i deny user from entering special characters in textbox using jquery?

```
special characters are like \ / ? * [ or ]
```

Comment: Stop enter? What does these correctors correct? Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can achieve this using javascript only

call the below function in KeyPress event of text box

```
function AlphaNumericOnly(e,isAlphaonly)
{
   // copyright 1999 Idocs, Inc. http://www.idocs.com
   var key = [e.keyCode||e.which];

   var keychar = String.fromCharCode([e.keyCode||e.which]);
   keychar = keychar.toLowerCase();

   if(isAlphaonly=='true')
         checkString="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   else 
         checkString="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

   if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || 
         (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
        return true;
   else if (((checkString).indexOf(keychar) > -1))
        return true;
   else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
    $(function () {
        //Add handler to input where the id ends with txtName 
        $("input[id$='txtUrl']").keypress(function (event) {
            if (!IsUrlReady(event)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    function IsUrlReady(e) {
        var key = [e.keyCode || e.which];
        var keychar = String.fromCharCode([e.keyCode || e.which]).toLowerCase();

        // 8 = backspace
        // 9 = tab
        //13 = enter key
        //35 = end | #
        //36 = home | $
        //37 - (direction) left | %
        //38 - (direction) up | &
        //39 - (direction) right | '
        //40 - (direction) down | (

        if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40)) {
            var pattern = new RegExp("['#$%&\(]");
            return !pattern.test(keychar);
        } else {
            var pattern = new RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9_-]");
            return pattern.test(keychar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network - KeyboardEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Key_names_and_Char_values

Answer (score 0):

check the keycodes within a `keydown` or `keyup` event handler.

```
$('input').bind('keydown', function(e){
   if(e.shiftKey){
     switch(e.which){
           case 55:{   // slash
                return(false);
           }
           case 187:{   // *
                return(false);
           }
           // and so forth
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: pasting was not part of the question anyways

Answer (score 0):

Like @Reigel pointed out, listening for keyboard entries can easily be bypassed by simply pasting the content so I think you would be better off with something like the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

It has *tons* of features, like custom validation rules so you can have it validate after your own custom rules (obviously). Below is an example of how you can have the validation trigger when the watched field's content changes (rather than waiting until the form is submitted), be it by typing or pasting:

```
$("#myTextField").change(function() {
    if(!$(this).valid()) {
        /* do something, show an alert, or whatever you need it to do */
    }
});
```

I won't go into greater detail on how to use this plugin because SO is already full of examples, but I hope it does set you on the right direction.